# Java method call gives syntax error

Tags: java, methods, syntax, call

Eclipse claims I have a syntax error in my call to a method on an object (quarterOneBudget). I don't understand what makes it say "Syntax error on token 'addCategory', Identifer expected after this token."

```
public class BudgetSpreadSheetTest {
    // Create a new spreadsheet and add some budget categories.
    BudgetSpreadSheet quarterOneBudget = new BudgetSpreadSheet();
    quarterOneBudget.addCategory();
    quarterOneBudget.addCategory();

}
```

It seems to me like my method call is just fine. I have defined "addCategory" in my BudgetSpreadSheet as follows.

```
public void addCategory(){
    // Create a new category
    BudgetCategory category = new BudgetCategory();

    // Add it to the array list
    categories.add(category);

    // Update the distribution chart
    this.distributionChart.addItem(category.getName(), category.getSpent());
}
```

Does anybody see why I am getting the syntax error?

Comment: Call to `quarterOneBudget.addCategory();` should be from a method in BudgetSpreadSheetTest class

Comment: You're code isn't within a method, it's within the class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make those calls to `addCategory()` directly inside a class, instead of in a method within the class. You need to put that code either in a method or in an [initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: While an initializer block would work, more often than not the constructor of the class will be most appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it up in a method in the class `BudgetSpreadSheetTest`, like

```
public void dummyMethod(){
    quarterOneBudget.addCategory();
    quarterOneBudget.addCategory();
}
```